# Matrix adjacent elements combinations in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, matrix

I have this Matrix:

```
A B C

D E F

G H I
```

I want to get all possible combinations of **adjacent** cells and **diagonal** cells with a lenght of **3**, for example:

Starting from A:

```
 - *ABC* right right
 - *ABE* right down
 - *ABF* right diagonal-right
 - *ABD* right diagonal-left
 - ecc ecc
```

I tried to create a new class called "lettera", with as key the letter, and with a member that indicates the pointer to right, left, down, up ecc. And also with a member called "sequenza", a string that concatenate every letter it touch.

For example if a have as key, "B", i have  B->down == *E, B->left == *A, B->right == *C and so on...
And it works. Then I put a counter for each letter: when it arrives at 3 it should stop determinating combinations.

Then the core of the problem: the path for each letter to follow... I tried do create a recursive function, but it doenst work.

Can you please help me by watching this or by suggesting me another way?

Thanks a lot.

The code:

```
    void decisione(lettera *c) {

            if (c == nullptr) return ;

            c->count++;
            c->sequenza = c->sequenza + c->key;

            if (c->count == 2) 
                    cout << "\n" << c->sequenza; 
                 //the sequence of letters accumulated in every call
            decisione(c->Up);
            decisione(c->Down);

        }
```

It gives me for example AAA and BBB and then it crashes =(

Comment: wouldn't ``B -> down`` be ``E`` ?

Comment: yes it's true, thanks. Mistake... A edited it

Comment: Run in a debugger to isolate and fix the crash.

Comment: Done it, when i have no crashes it gives me only AAA BBB ecc. So my solution doesn't logically works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start at A, where can you go? B and D. Suppose you go to B, now, where can you go? A, C and E. You've already been in A and you don't want to return, so you only have C and E. Suppose you pick C, as you have already picked three letters the function stops and then you pick E and so on (I'm not choosing diagonal neighbors), here is the program:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int a[] = {-1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1}, b[] = {-1,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,1},cont;
char s[3],mat[3][3];
bool flag[9];

void display() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) printf("%c",s[i]);
  puts("");
}

void show(int x,int y) {//You are in mat[x][y]
  s[cont] = mat[x][y];
  if(cont == 2) {
    display();
    return;
  }
  flag[mat[x][y] - 'A'] = true;
  int xx,yy;
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    xx = x + a[i], yy = y + b[i];
    if(0 <= xx and xx < 3 and 0 <= yy and yy < 3 and !flag[mat[xx][yy] - 'A']) {
      ++cont;
      show(xx,yy);
      --cont;
    }
  }
  flag[mat[x][y] - 'A'] = false;

}

int main() {
  cont = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
      mat[i][j] = ('A' + 3*i + j);
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
      show(i,j); //You start from mat[i][j]: {'A','B','C',...,'I'}
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I really don't understand your code =(

Comment: what part exactly you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand the usage of "flag" and why you do .. - 'A'... What is the general idea of your solution?

Comment: I use flag to keep a record of the letters I have used so far, I put - 'A' because the array only supports indexes from 0 to 8, if I put flag['A'] it will try to access an array out of limits, that's why I put - 'A', when it checks 'A' it will check flag['A' - 'A'] = flag[0].

I explained the idea of the algorithm before the code, but if you don't understand it, keep asking :D